# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to decode Base64

Tags: java, android, base64

I am trying to decode a `Base64` encoded string in Android. The string is `751 bytes` long.

`byte[] b = Base64.decodeBase64(b_b64);`

I am using `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` library for the function.

But I am getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=255; index=-65
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.isBase64(Base64.java:142)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.discardNonBase64(Base64.java:483)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:379)
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Just a guess, but `index=-65` looks suspicious.

Comment: Not enough information: how did you instantiate `Base64` object (what parameters did you pass to the contractor?), what is `b_b64` ?

Comment: @Gendarme I didn’t get you. What is wrong ?

Comment: @alfasin `b_b64` Its the base encoded string.

Comment: A negative index. I have never seen such a thing before.

Comment: Again, that's not enough information...

Comment: How did you obtain this string?  Please include the relevent  code.

Comment: @alfasin Let me check it.

Comment: @jgm the string that you're passing is not base64 so it cannot be decode as such, the exception is thrown from the check `isBase64()` - which you can see in the stacktrace.

Comment: Pipe the string into `base64 -d`, see what error pops out.